# Ruby on rails form validation for user profiles advice needed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems

I have one model that holds validation rules for my edit_profiles page. On the edit profile page I'm using jquery accordion to split user edit_profile into different sections for users to edit information. Each section is a separate form.

e.g.

Basic info (form 1)
Personal Stats (form 2)
Favourite things (form 3)
About me (form 4)

My problem is successfully filling out information on one form and clicking update is unsuccessful because other validation rules that have been set are firing in because other forms are failing validation because they have not yet be filled in.

I've tried to use the validation_group gem but this seems to have no affect.
I'd like to know if there is an easy way to do this?

Can't I just bunch up validation rules for each form and put them in separate methods and only make them come into play when the update button from a matching form has been clicked?

So if the update button on form 1 is clicked the form_one_validations method would be fire for example and the unrelated validation methods won't.

I would really really appreciate an example of how to do this.

This is the action responsible for y edit_profile view:

```
  def edit_profile

  @profile = Profile.find_by_user_id(current_user.id)

  end
```

It is based inside my profiles controller.

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using :allow_blank
This way the fields don't have to be filled in but all other important validation rules are still enforced if they need to be.

Answer (score 0):

I can propose you such approach: you can add additional fields to your model, something like "basic_info_completed" which will be set up once after user has filled all corresponding information. And make all necessary validations conditional and perform them only when such field is set to true. So before user fills all fields of profile section, they are all can be edited without validation, but after profile fields are completed, validation is turned on for that part of profile.

Comment: I wanted to actually protect the db at all times. Won't that mean my db is more open to an attack with no form of validation protecting it?

Comment: In this case I suppose only two states of fields : all fields of the group are empty(null), all fields of group are set(valid).